# How to insert a row without any values so that all columns assume their default value?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to do something simple - insert a row into MySQL (with PHP) but without values.  The MySQL table will already have the default values it needs, so I don't need to insert any values.  How would the insert statement look without values to insert?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ()
```

Comment: Working with mariadb  as well - 10.0.31-MariaDB

Answer (score 14):

In SQL Server it is like this.

```
insert into TableName default values
```

Comment: This didn't work for me with MySQL - and the question was about MySQL (see tags). Or did I something wrong and this syntax usually work in MySQL too?

Comment: @Pavel Don't know why my answer was selected as the correct one. The answer by nobody works in MySQL.

Comment: Works with Postgres too (unlike other answers). Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The proper way is to provide an empty values list and let the fields take their default values implicitly:

```
INSERT INTO `table` () VALUES();
```

Alternatively you can use the `DEFAULT` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`Col1`, `Col2`, ...) VALUES(DEFAULT, DEFAULT, ...);
```

Or (assuming you're giving values for all the columns) just:

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES(DEFAULT, DEFAULT, ...);
```

---

All the required information can be found in [the documentation for `INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

> **If you do not specify a list of column names for INSERT ... VALUES or
>   INSERT ... SELECT, values for every column in the table must be
>   provided by the VALUES list or the SELECT statement.** If you do not
>   know the order of the columns in the table, use DESCRIBE tbl_name to
>   find out.
>
> [..]
>
> **If you are not running in strict SQL mode, any column not explicitly
>   given a value is set to its default (explicit or implicit) value.** For
>   example, if you specify a column list that does not name all the
>   columns in the table, unnamed columns are set to their default values.
>   Default value assignment is described in Section 10.1.4, “Data Type
>   Default Values”. See also Section 1.8.6.2, “Constraints on Invalid
>   Data”.
>
> [..]
>
> **Use the keyword DEFAULT to set a column explicitly to its default
>   value.** This makes it easier to write INSERT statements that assign
>   values to all but a few columns, because it enables you to avoid
>   writing an incomplete VALUES list that does not include a value for
>   each column in the table. Otherwise, you would have to write out the
>   list of column names corresponding to each value in the VALUES list.
>
> [..]
>
> If both the column list and the VALUES list are empty, INSERT creates
>   a row with each column set to its default value:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO tbl_name () VALUES();
> ```
>
> [..]
>
> **In strict mode, an error occurs if any column doesn't have a default
>   value.** Otherwise, MySQL uses the implicit default value for any
>   column that does not have an explicitly defined default.

Comment: `INSERT INTO table_name DEFAULT` doesn't work in MySQL. Use `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES()` instead.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';` gives `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`, so I believe it's SQL Strict mode. When l execute query `INSERT INTO table_name DEFAULT;` it gives error `SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT' at line 1`. I have pointed that you've given two alternatives and the first one doesn't work in case of MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `default values`:

```
insert YourTable default values
```